# jqplot and stacked chart data labels

Tags: jqplot

I am having a problem with jqplot and positioning the data labels on stacked charts.

I am charting three data values per column. The problem is when one of the data values is very small like 1% the data label overlaps that of the adjacent data value.

I have uploaded an image here:
http://img84.imageshack.us/img84/1305/capturell.jpg

What I would like to do is be able to position the data labels in the middle of each bar. Is this possible?

Here is the code I am using:

```
 plot1 = $.jqplot(id, data, {
    seriesDefaults:{
      renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      rendererOptions: {
         fillToZero: true,
          highlightMouseOver: false,
        highlightMouseDown: false,
        highlightColor: null,
        barDirection: 'horizontal'
      },
         pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15 }
    },
    title:{text: title,fontSize: 16},

    series:[
      {label: data_labels[0] },
      {label: data_labels[1]}

    ],
    seriesColors: [  "#4879a6", "#d9321d"], 

                // Rotate the bar shadow as if bar is lit from top right.
    shadowAngle: 135,

    axes: {
      xaxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        tickInterval: 20,
        tickOptions: {formatString: '%d\%' ,fontSize: 14}
      },
      yaxis: {
         renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
         ticks: ticks,
         tickOptions: {fontSize: 14}
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have not used jqplot very much. But two pointers: 1. Why do you have a negative edge tolerance? 2. You can try "dataLabelNudge" property of the renderer of jqplot

Comment: Hi Srini - I was playing around with the edge tolerance, thats why its negative. It doesnt really affect things since the data labels arnt that close to the edge of the chart.

Comment: I think the "dataLabelNudge" property is only for Pie and Donut charts.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that seriesDefaults just passes the same value to every instance of a series where its not already defined. so...

```
 seriesDefaults:{pointLabels: {show: true, stackedValue: false, location:'s'}},
```

is the same as

```
 series:[
             {pointLabels: {show: true, stackedValue: false, location:'s'}},           
             {pointLabels: {show: true, stackedValue: false, location:'s'}},
             {pointLabels: {show: true, stackedValue: false, location:'s'}}            
             ]
```

on the jqplots site he shows this example.
http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/point-labels.html

that shows a value called y-padding that is passed to pointLabels, that should do the trick.  That same example shows how to pass custom point value markers within the data array being passed to jqplot. It wouldn't shock me if you could slip it some html on the side to style the data markers.

```
 var data = [[x,y,tooltipValue],[x,y,null]];
```

Hope this helps, or at least gets you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

try this `dataLabelPositionFactor` proprety